# Separating lines in a file by even and odd numbers

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, bufferedreader

I have a file that is set up like:

```
10   10
12   32
38   12
```

I need to put the lines in the even slots in one array and the lines in the odd slots in another array. I am new to java and I have no idea how to do this. I have been searching the internet for hours and have not found anything. Please help me! I will really appreciate it!

I am using a Buffered Reader to read in the file. I have already written a program that reads in the file and puts all the lines in an array, now I just need to know how to code it to separate the lines. So the lines 1,3,5,7,9 will be in one array and lines 2,4,6,8 will be in another.

Code that I have for putting them in one array:

```
 private static final String FILE = "file.txt";
    private static Point[] points;


    public static void main(final String[] args){
        try{
            final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(FILE)));
            points = new Point[Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())];
            int i = 0;
            int xMax = 0;
            int yMax = 0;
            while(br.ready()){
                final String[] split = br.readLine().split("\t");
                final int x = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                final int y = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                xMax = Math.max(x, xMax);
                yMax = Math.max(y, yMax);
                points[i++] = new Point(x, y);




            }
```

Comment: Can you share the snippet of code you have now for reading it in - and maybe declare the two variables you want to split things in to? then it will be easy to show you how to get the last bit...

Comment: you can read line by line.

Comment: If you have an array with "all the lines", they you can do a loop: `if (lineNumber % 2 == 0) ...`

Comment: Alright I have posted the code. And Floris, that is an idea.. I wonder if it would be able to be implemented in the code that I already have fairly easily though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    for (int i = 0; (line = br.readLine()) != null; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            list1.add(line);
        } else {
            list2.add(line);
        }
    }
    String[] even = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
    String[] odd = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
```

Comment: Yeah +1 because this allows files of variable lengths. Didn't think of that. Also way more elegant with the counting variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] even = new String[100];
String[] odd = new String[100];
int counter = 0;
String text;

while(text=readLine() != null) {
    if(counter%2 == 0) {
         even[counter/2] = text;
    } else {
         odd[(counter-1)/2] = text;
    }

     counter++;
}
```

You will need to adjust the size of the arrays according to the number of lines the file has.

What does the code do: the loop keeps reading lines. counter%2 == 0 is true if counter is even. If counter is even, counter/2 will be an integer without remainder, so nothing is lost. If counter is odd, the same is true for (counter-1)/2.

Comment: Yep... that's the rest of the loop I started in my comment. (+1).

Comment: Cheers! Thought a bit of code would do more to explain it here.

Comment: Interesting... I like it.. Let me try some things with it.